# One way binding + dynamic binding in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, data-binding

I will start by explaining what we are trying to achieve.

We have just jumped on the Angular bandwagon and are building a prototype with it to see what it is capable of.

Currently there is a load of data (grades in this case) on the server and we display that data using Angular.

The following is the code we use:

```
<ul class="phones">
    <li class="list-group-item" onclick="toggleExpandedView(this, true, 500)" ng-repeat="grade in grades | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">

        <span ng-show="grade.comment"><img src="../Content/images/comment.gif"/></span>

        <a class="btn btn-primary editButton" style="float: right; position: absolute; right:10px;" ng-href="#/grades/{{grade.gradeId}}">Edit</a>

        <div class="heading1"><a ng-href="{{grade.url}}" target="_blank">{{grade.gradeValue}}</a></div>
        <div>Provided by <a href="#">{{grade.assessorFirstname}} {{grade.assessorLastname}}</a> on {{grade.dateModifiedFormatted}} </div>

        <div class="expandedGrade" onclick="childDivClick(event)" style="display: none" id="grade-{{grade.gradeId}}">
            <label>Attachments</label>{{grade.attachmentCount}}
            <br />

            <span ng-hide="editing" ng-click="editing = true"><b>{{grade.comment || 'No comments yet'}}</b></span>
            <form ng-show="editing" ng-submit="editing = false">
                <input type="text" ng-model="grade.comment" placeholder="Comment" ng-required />
                <br />
                <input id="saveChanges" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveChanges(this, grade)" text="Save changes" />
            </form>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see we have a parent `ul` and for each `grade` in `grades` we simply display a `li` and a `div` that is hidden and when you click on the `li` we use `jQuery` to animate and display the hidden div. In the child div we have a comments field which users can update and click `save`. On save the current object gets fired back to the server however we are concerned about the fact that Angular has to go through all 2000 grades until it finds the one we are updating (due to two way binding) and this means that everything will be really slow and we cannot afford that.

### This is what we want to achieve:

**1** We want to bind the data one way so that we can display the list of all grades on the screen and as soon as they are all displayed we want to somehow remove the bindings.

**2.** When users update the comments for a particular grade we then want to dynamically bind that particular grade so that Angular knows exactly which one it has to update without having to go through the whole collection of 2000+ grades.

I have find a [tutorial](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/removing-the-unneeded-watches/)  however I am still unsure how to integrate that into my code.

I have also watched [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyYpHIOrk_Y) and I understand the concept behind it but again, I am struggling to write something that actually works ( we have just started using Angular so I am pretty much a newbie)

Could anyone out there point me in the right direction and provide me with some code samples that would solve the issue we are facing? Any advice and help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your case is specific and so a little bit complicated but you could have a look at the [bindonce module](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) and then use ng-class with ng-bind (as class) to achieve lazy binding. I never tried that, it's just an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a directive

The logic should go like this

- use a service to hold your grades
- inject the service into your directive
- make a copy and just bind the 'read only view' in your directive
- you could watch the service for changes and makes updates as needed
  in your directive
- as far a lazy loading / updating when needed - use a data service
  and call the data service for an update whenever the trigger fires
- if your trigger needs to come as a push from some other 'web service' consider a technology
  like http://socket.io/

I can put together an example if you would like to see how the services and directives should interact

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer - if you have time (and can be bothered) could you put a simple example to demonstrate it? Once again, thank you for your help